# ResourcesCompat.getColor() without Context: error NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-resources

I use this code (Kotlin extension)

```
val Int.color: Int
    get() = ResourcesCompat.getColor(Resources.getSystem(), this, null)
```

Log

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050031
```

Why it crash? Thanks.

Comment: What color are you trying to get?

Comment: The 2nd parameter should be the id of a color.   ex. R.color.red

Comment: I use:
```
R.color.colorRed.color
```

I defined colorRed in values/colors.xml.

I think issue around code Resources.getSytem(), but I don't why.

Comment: Your second parameter is 'this', I believe it should be R.color.colorRed

Comment: Thank @eimmer for answer, but I use Kotlin Extension, this code is right syntax.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how are you passing the color id?